# Why this code is not looping (while)?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, decrement

```
int main()
{
    int i=3;
    while(i--)
        cout << i << " ";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Result:
2 1 0

Why not: 2 1 0 -1 -2 -3 ...(loop)?

Comment: Because `0` evaluates to `false` in boolean contexts

Comment: Because 0 is "falsey"?

Comment: For compatiblity with C, `0` is implicitly convertible to `false`, and non-zero is implicitly convertible to `true`.

Comment: `i` is the same as `i != 0` in a boolean expression.

Comment: Use `for (int i = 3; /*Empty*/; --i)` to have infinite loop.

Comment: or `while(true) cout << i-- << " ";` if you want to keep the while loop

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not outputting what you're expecting is because of that magic 0.

0, in C++ and most other languages, evaluates to boolean false. All other numbers are true. In this case, you're using the value of `i` as your loop condition, so, when `i == 0`, the loop stops and the program moves on.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as `i` decrements to zero, `i--` is false, so the `while` stops.

Answer (score 0):

> Why not: 2 1 0 -1 -2 -3 ...(loop)?

The loop breaks when the expression in the conditional evaluates to false. That happens when the value of `i` is zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    int i=3;
    while(i--)
        cout << i << " ";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Once `i` hits 0 it's not true anymore therefore it'll end the loop.

```
while( true )
{
    --i;
}
```

would be better here.

Answer (score 0):

When using a while loop, `1` means `true` and `0` means `false`.

So in your case, as `i` is being decremented at every iteration in the loop, at some point, `i` becomes `0`,
which is `false` and the loop comes to an end.